# How to select all SQL duplicates in multiple columns given one match

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm relatively new to SQL.

Is there any way, in one SQL statement, given a match to look for in a SELECT statement (say… WHERE email = 'test@test.com'), return all matches of that email AND anyone who matches another specified field from the results of that first SELECT statement?

For example, say two users had the email test@test.com, and one (or both) of them had a dti_id of 47.  There are other users in the table with a dti_id of 47 who don't have an email address of test@test.com, but I want them all returned in the same query.  I can figure out how to do it in like a dozen SQL calls, but I'm fairly confident that it can be written more efficiently in one call doing a JOIN or a subquery or something.

So instead of just saying

```
SELECT * WHERE email = 'test@test.com'
```

I want the same results that I'd get when I do

```
SELECT * WHERE email = 'test@test.com' OR dti_id = 47 OR dti_id = 51 OR username = 'test';
```

Where the ORs are added in as those are results from email = 'test@test.com'.

Comment: Please show us some sample data and the expected output (remember that you can format text using `<pre>` tags)

Comment: I second the first comment. The schema of the database table would also be helpful.

Comment: I just added in some sample SQL, does that explain it better?  The schema is just a users table with a few columns about the user.  I just picked dti_id and username at random, because it really doesn't matter what they're called.  Just other specific columns (one is an integer, the other is text) in the table that need to be matched.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an explicit self join.  However, I think it is easier to understand the logic by using `in` or `exists` in the `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.email = 'test@test.com' or
      exists (select 1
              from table t2
              where t2.dti_id = t.dti_id and
                    t2.email = 'test@test.com'
             );
```

This corresponds rather directly to the problem as you state it.  Select all the rows from the table where the email is whatever and also select the rows that match on a certain field to a row with that email.

For performance reasons, this query will work best with an index on `table(dti_id, email)`.

Comment: And "table" should be replaced by the name of my table?

Comment: @DanGoodspeed . . . Yes.  Your question doesn't include the name of the table.

Comment: I spent hours trying to get this to work, and it just hangs when I use it as you wrote it.  Removing everything after the OR stops the hang.  I did figure out you left out the * for the SELECT, are you sure everything else is correct?

Comment: @DanGoodspeed . . . How large is the table?

Comment: Probably about 10,000 records or so.

Comment: Have you created the index suggested in the query?

Comment: Guess I'm not sure how to go about doing that.